# Python: count occurances of a given char in a string

Tags: python, string, count

How would I take a string in Python like "/bin/usr/proga/file.c" and count the occurrences of the '/' character?

So, for the above example, the function would return 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
"/bin/usr/proga/file.c".count("/")
```

[Refer to the documentation for strings](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s="/bin/usr/proga/file.c"
>>> s.count("/")
4
>>> len(s.split("/"))-1
4
```