# Count the number of times a particular string appears in a given word

Tags: python

How to write a program that prints the number of times a particular string appears in a given word.
For example: if I'm looking for the string 'dad' in a word 'asdadgfrdad'
             output should be 2.

```py
def numStrings(a):
    strings = 'dad'
    result = 0
    for char in a:
        if char in strings:
            result = result + 1
    print result

numStrings("asdadgfrdad")
```

But this gives me the number of times the letters d,a are present in the given word. How to correct this?

Comment: Strings have a builtin method for that: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count

Comment: Intendation is important in Python.

Comment: A good question starts with [a good title](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do you know about indexing strings, and doing `for i in len(a)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: count occurances of a given char in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683830/python-count-occurances-of-a-given-char-in-a-string)

Comment: Do you need overlapping strings? eg: What's the correct count for "dadadad"?

Comment: Another tip: the pythonic naming  convention is `snake_case` instead of `camelCase`.

Comment: I need for overlapping strings. Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short and simple pythonic way to do it would be

```
'asdadgfrdad'.count('dad')
```

However, your answer may or may not be what you expect when you look at something like `'dadad'.count('dad')` which returns 1 instead of 2. This is because `str.count` returns the number of **non-overlapping occurrences** of substring. On the other hand, if you want to find the number of overlapping substrings, you'll have to use the following code:

```
haystack = 'dadad'
needle = 'dad'
sum(haystack[i:i+len(needle)] == needle for i in range(len(haystack)))
```

Comment: Can u please tell me where to use the last code? i tried including it in my code but i'm not getting the desired output.

Comment: You'll have to use the last line as an expression, for example `num_repeats = sum(haystack[i:i+len(needle)] == needle for i in range(len(haystack)))` and then use `num_repeats` variable as you would like. (such as `print`ing it etc)